# What if object is located at highest address possible

Tags: c++, memory, stl, iterator, containers

What if `static_cast< std::uintptr_t >(&obj) == std::numeric_limits< std::uintptr_t >::max() - sizeof(obj) + 1`? Say, `obj` is the last element in continious STL container (or native array), how should it be handled by STL algorithms, that uses ranges of iterators? I sure iterators (even debug versions) of continious containers designed in such a way, that they uses addresses (non-dereferenceable, but valid) of past-the-end element.

I know, that common design of operating systems is to allocate stack at highest address possible, and for uniform memory systems there placed return address of first function called (at least `main`). But there are systems, where it is possible to allocate stack on any address (for every process, I want).

Comment: The only way you would get the "last" address is if the operating system would map it to your process, and that would be a very broken operating system just because "one beyond the end" is such a common way to mark the end of something.

Comment: The question seems irrelevant. The standard requires that end iterators exist and function. Therefore, if there is no way for a system to handle the end iterator for an array where the last element is at the highest `uintptr_t` value, then it is illegal for the implementation to *put* such an array element there in the first place.

Comment: Iterators are getting invalidated if modification requires reallocating/moving data.

Comment: @myaut I can move actual data and change reference to it into my own iterator implementation. Double indirection and intrusive iterators are not illegal, I think.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible, because there has to be at least one address available for the past-the-end iterator.

So the implementation  has to solve this somehow, like not allocating objects at the top of memory (but code maybe), or leave room for one more address.

Comment: Is it citation from memory model definition?

Comment: @Orient: There's nothing to cite. It's an outgrowth of the need for an end iterator to exist. The implementation cannot do things that would make an end iterator impossible.

Comment: @NicolBolas If system uses ASLR and my code is PIC, how can implementation proves, that last byte (which in turn is static data (or [datum](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37033859/1430927)) placed into .text section) is not on maximum address possible. Say, size of code section is multiple of 4096 and hardware is x86/x64 - the page can be allocated at highest virtual address. Otherwise I can't use last page of 4G memory on x86 for C++, isn't it?

Comment: @Orient: "*Otherwise I can't use last page of 4G memory on x86 for C++, isn't it?*" Given your example, it would be more accurate to say that ASLR should not attempt to load static data sections into the last virtual address page. And the only "STL object" that would affect would be `array`; all others are dynamically allocated.

Comment: @NicolBolas So, system implementors should be awared about C++ issues? I think they shouldn't even know about its existance.

Comment: @Orient: You say "C++ issues" as though pointer arithmetic and boundaries are the exclusive providence of C++.